# How do I resolve this Thonny pip install error?

Tags: python, pip, thonny

When I try to install any module in Thonny, I get the following error.  I think I can fix it by removing the "--user" part of the install command, but that gets input automatically.  How do I change the pip install command?

/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --user BeautifulSoup --disable-pip-version-check

ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
Process returned with code 1

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is for Python 2.7. For Python 3+ use `beautifulsoup4`, `bs4` for short.

Comment: thank you!  I'll use bs4 in the future, but I still get the same error when I try to install.  I get this error for any module I try to install.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: "*I get this error for any module I try to install.*" Then try to find out why `pip` always thinks you pass `--target`. Look into [`pip.conf`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/) config file. Check environment variables with `set | grep -F PIP_`